# Docker Error response from daemon: failed to mount local volume

Tags: linux, docker, ubuntu-20.04, usb-drive

I am trying to use a USB drive or an external storage as volume for a mysql docker container. I'm using Linux Ubuntu 22.04.1 LTS as host and docker 20.10.14.

If I mount the USB drive to a directory `~/media` and run `sudo docker run --name mysql00 -p 3306:3306 -e MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD=password -v ~/media:/var/lib/mysql mysql` it works fine.

Now, if I try to create a volume using the usb drive with:

```
sudo docker volume create --driver local --opt type=overlay2 --opt device=/dev/sda2 foo
```

The volume is created and I can inspect it:

```
[
    {
        "CreatedAt": "2022-10-10T16:04:44Z",
        "Driver": "local",
        "Labels": {},
        "Mountpoint": "/var/snap/docker/common/var-lib-docker/volumes/foo/_data",
        "Name": "foo",
        "Options": {
            "device": "/dev/sda2",
            "type": "overlay2"
        },
        "Scope": "local"
    }
]
```

However, when I run:

```
sudo docker run  --name mysql99  -p 3306:3306  -e MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD=password  -v foo:/var/lib/mysql mysql
```

I get the following error:

```
docker: Error response from daemon: failed to mount local volume: mount /dev/sda2:/var/snap/docker/common/var-lib-docker/volumes/foo/_data: no such device.
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

The `--opt type=` of `local` driver is used to specify the actual type of your local filesystem specified in `--opt device=`. Therefore, you should put the actual FS type (i.e. `ext4`, `btrfs`, `exfat`, `ntfs`, etc.) to `--opt type=`.

For example, if `/dev/sda2` is formatted as ext4, replace `--opt type=overlay2` with `--opt type=ext4`.

To determine the type of a filesystem, use either `fdisk -l` or `lsblk -o +FSTYPE` command.